# How to my fix layout when label reaches 2 lines

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a label and inputbox(form) and I use bootstrap for *CSS* but my problem is when my label become 2 lines/paragraph my layout is not fixed or equal. How can I make layout looks like primary information even if text is 2 lines/paragraph. 
*Check image below*

[image: Check diff. between primary and view]

and I use this code

```
<div class="col-md-12"> 
<div class="col-lg-2">
   <label class="control-label"><?php echo $required_notice.$val_option['option']?><?php if(!empty($options_lang[$key][$key_option]->hint)):?><i class="icon-question-sign hint" data-hint="<?php echo $options_lang[$key][$key_option]->hint;?>"></i><?php endif;?></label>
   <div class="controls">
      <?php 

       $cur_value = isset($estate['option'.$val_option['id'].'_'.$key])?$estate['option'.$val_option['id'].'_'.$key]:'';

       echo form_input('option'.$val_option['id'].'_'.$key, set_value('option'.$val_option['id'].'_'.$key, $cur_value), 'class="form-control '.$val_option['type'].'" id="inputOption_'.$key.'_'.$val_option['id'].'" strlen="'.strlen($cur_value).'" placeholder="'.$val_option['option'].'" '.$required_text.' '.$max_length_text)?>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Note: I'm using foreach for my fields.

Thank you.

Comment: show the label behind the input ?

Comment: you can use `text-overflow: ellipsis; ` if you want and add title="demo"  like : https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FMM3FT46CEXF

Answer (score 0):

If you like to have an ellipsis like the word would be like "your word is l..." then you have to apply following line of code to your label.

```
.your-label {
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
   display: block;
 }
```

if you got any problems do let me know :)

Comment: Thankyou! Good idea that ellipsis can solve the problem, but I want to show my the whole label name so people can understand the fields.

Comment: you can decrease the font size then :) but it is good to have ellipsis because you might have long text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex style from CSS. align-items: flex-end will align all input box from bottom not top. So it will looks better.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form> 
        <div class="col-lg-2">
         <label class="control-label"><?php echo $required_notice.$val_option['option']?><?php if(!empty($options_lang[$key][$key_option]->hint)):?><i class="icon-question-sign hint" data-hint="<?php echo $options_lang[$key][$key_option]->hint;?>"></i><?php endif;?></label>
         <div class="controls">
            <?php 

             $cur_value = isset($estate['option'.$val_option['id'].'_'.$key])?$estate['option'.$val_option['id'].'_'.$key]:'';

             echo form_input('option'.$val_option['id'].'_'.$key, set_value('option'.$val_option['id'].'_'.$key, $cur_value), 'class="form-control '.$val_option['type'].'" id="inputOption_'.$key.'_'.$val_option['id'].'" strlen="'.strlen($cur_value).'" placeholder="'.$val_option['option'].'" '.$required_text.' '.$max_length_text)?>

        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
```